# How do I upload files to httpd (www) folder in EC2?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, sftp, files, upload

As title said, how do I upload my php files into my newly installed httpd (/var/www/html) on a EC2 instance?

I am trying to use cyberduck(using sftp), but apperantly, when I connected to my EC2 instance, it shows nothing (no files, no folders). Am I missing something/some settings??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the rights the user you use to connect has. Try creating a separate which has sufficient rights to do this.

Comment: I cant login as root. It always said, please login as ec2-user instead of root. Then, I always login as ec2-user, and the problem always there Am I missing anything?

Comment: Log onto ssh, then invoke 'sudo -i', supply your password and make a new user with rights to the web-folder.

Comment: i am new to linux, can u write down the steps into your answer? Like, how to grant rights to users etc, so that I can accept your answer as best answer

Comment: OKay, i already give the user rights: "chown -R NewUser /var/www/html", but when I connect via cyberduck, it still display the files thats 2 level above the /var/ directory, and i cant see /var/www/html folder

Comment: IF you are connected with NewUser to ssh and you run the command 'touch /var/www/html' does this work?